# How to make my Radian console in the VS code display all coding result, not only the last line?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to make the Radian console in the VS code to display all coding results I run, not only the last line? It is quite inconvenient to run code line by line to see the whole result.

Below is the example from VS code:

```
r$> sum(ILD_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
    sum(ILD1_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
    sum(ILD2_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
[1] 9
```

It would be great if the results from VS code could be like the ones from RStudio:

```
> sum(ILD_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
[1] 4
> sum(ILD1_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
[1] 4
> sum(ILD2_HILIC_limma$pfdr<0.05, na.rm = T)
[1] 9
```

I tried to adjust the "Scrollback" feature in Visual Studio Code's Integrated Terminal, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Open the R terminal in VS Code by clicking on the R logo in the bottom left corner of the window and selecting "Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal".

In the terminal window, type the command `options(scipen = 999)` and press Enter. This will set the scipen option to a high value, which can sometimes cause R to display more decimal places for numeric output.

Run your code in the terminal as usual, and the output should now display all the results generated by your code, rather than just the last line.

It should work for Visual Studio Code Version: 1.75.0 and R Radian terminal.